# char* incompatible with parameter of LPWSTR for C++

Tags: c++, winapi, char

> char* incompatible with parameter of LPWSTR

```
void ConnectToEngine(char* path)
{

    pipin_w = pipin_r = pipout_w = pipout_r = NULL;
    sats.nLength = sizeof(sats);
    sats.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    sats.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

    CreatePipe(&pipout_r, &pipout_w, &sats, 0);
    CreatePipe(&pipin_r, &pipin_w, &sats, 0);

    sti.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW | STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    sti.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;
    sti.hStdInput = pipin_r;
    sti.hStdOutput = pipout_w;
    sti.hStdError = pipout_w;

    CreateProcess(NULL, path, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &sti, &pi);
}
```

Any other ways to solve this problem?

Comment: And? Yes, they are not compatible: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230355.aspx

Comment: Any reason you are using char string instead of standard strings?

Comment: @JakeFreeman please define "standard strings"

Comment: @Jabberwocky `std::string`

Comment: @jak: So `std::wstring` is not a *"standard string"* type? And yes, there *are* reasons to not use C++ string types. It's far less troublesome to keep things C at an interface boundary.

Comment: [Working with Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/learnwin32/working-with-strings) answers all your questions, including those you didn't ask.

Comment: Also -- *do not `C`-cast to a different string type to get rid of the compiler error*.  You're lucky enough to have stopped at the error and asked the question here, than do what a lot of unaware programmers do, which is to apply an ill-advised cast to the type and then wonder why their program produces gibberish characters.

Comment: @bar: That's not correct. [CreateProcessW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) requires a **mutable** string as its second argument. A string literal won't do.

Comment: This question has been closed as a duplicate with 3 references. And gets an upvote. The tooltip on the upvote arrow reads: *"This question shows research effort"*. I'm at a total loss. Would the upvoter please be so kind as to provide rationale for their decision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's true.

If you insist on having a `char*` parameter, call `CreateProcessA` instead of `CreateProcess`. Otherwise, make `path` an `LPWSTR` too and bring your program into this millenium.